# Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another columns of the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Table: names

```
Id  name    namemaster
--  ----    ----------
1   tomato  tomato/999
2   lettuce lettuce/999
3   carrot  carrot/999
```

In oracle SQL, how do I run an sql update query that can update table colum "names.namemaster" with name of the table colum "names.name" using the same id? 
So the end result I would get is:

Table: names

```
Id  name    namemaster
--  ----    ----------
1   tomato  tomato
2   lettuce lettuce
3   carrot  carrot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want a simple `update`?

```
update names
    set namemaster = name;
```